# Unable to reload TableView Data in iOS App

Tags: ios, tableview

I find my self out of ideas trying to get this app to work. My app uses a split view to show to lists. the "Master" list should hold a list of the user's Facebook friends. Since the app does not force you to login, if you're not logged in yet it shows "You have no friends" in the list till you've logged in. My problem is that once I've loaded all the friends and call [self.tableView reloadData] my program crashes some in there, and despite my best attempts at debugging it I can't find it. The method is

```
    - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
    {
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && ([result count] > 0)) {
            result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        switch (((Facebook *)[Facebook shared]).currentCall) {
            case graphUserFriends:
            {
                _friends = [NSMutableArray array];
                NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                if ([resultData count] > 0) 
                {
                    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[resultData count] && i < 25; i++) 
                    {
                        NSDictionary *friendDictionary = [resultData objectAtIndex:i];
                        FbFriend * f = [[[FbFriend alloc] initWithName:[friendDictionary objectForKey:@"name"] Id:[friendDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]] autorelease];
                        [_friends addObject:f];
                    }
                }
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The whole source code (and Xcode 4 project) can be downloaded from https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=04b38cdd7b38bb7f&resid=4B38CDD7B38BB7F!798&parid=4B38CDD7B38BB7F!470&authkey=!API4iVva95nZFL8

Console (At Crash):

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug 15 16:03:10 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 48870.
Catchpoint 3 (throw)Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0156ecf0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x013c9674 in -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] ()
#2  0x00454805 in -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] ()
#3  0x0026427a in -[UITableViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] ()
#4  0x0020f548 in -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] ()
#5  0x00211722 in -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] ()
#6  0x000c17c7 in -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] ()
#7  0x000c12c1 in -[UITableView reloadData] ()
#8  0x0000247e in -[MasterViewController request:didLoad:] (self=0x6a491e0, _cmd=0x12e65, request=0x681e930, result=0x6824250) at /Users/CheckM8/Documents/Xcode 4/Projects/iPeople4/iPeople4/MasterViewController.m:46
#9  0x00009d36 in -[FBRequest handleResponseData:] (self=0x681e930, _cmd=0x1397a, data=0x6a76c60) at /Users/CheckM8/Documents/Xcode 4/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-74358cd/src/FBRequest.m:261
#10 0x0000a357 in -[FBRequest connectionDidFinishLoading:] (self=0x681e930, _cmd=0xade62e, connection=0x681ec40) at /Users/CheckM8/Documents/Xcode 4/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-74358cd/src/FBRequest.m:346
#11 0x00a29a59 in ___NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 ()
#12 0x00a27e94 in __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 ()
#13 0x00a28eb7 in -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] ()
#14 0x00a27e4f in -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] ()
#15 0x00a27fd5 in -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] ()
#16 0x0096cf6a in _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading ()
#17 0x0398fbbd in URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFinishLoading ()
#18 0x03a5c5ea in URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload ()
#19 0x03986298 in URLConnectionClient::processEvents ()
#20 0x03a5c16b in non-virtual thunk to URLConnectionInstanceData::multiplexerClientPerform() ()
#21 0x03986137 in MultiplexerSource::perform ()
#22 0x013b197f in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#23 0x01314b73 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#24 0x01314454 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#25 0x01313db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#26 0x01313ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#27 0x012c6879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#28 0x012c693e in GSEventRun ()
#29 0x00034a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#30 0x00001d82 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffed64) at /Users/CheckM8/Documents/Xcode 4/Projects/iPeople4/iPeople4/main.m:16
#31 0x00001cf5 in start ()
```

Comment: Do you have NSZombies enabled? (just an idea)

Comment: Tried them, but they didn't report anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made the classic memory management mistake: You're directly accessing your ivars and it burned you.

```
_friends = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This is an under-retain (which will crash later), and also a possible leak if `_friends` had a prior value. You should always use accessors for your ivars except in dealloc and init:

```
self.friends = [NSMutableArray array];
...
[self.friends addObject:f];
```

---

EDIT: From your stacktrace, your bug is in your table view data source's `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. It looks like you're reading off the end of your array.

Comment: Added it as a nonatomic and retain property but it still crashed the same. Good idea but didn't solve this problem yet, thanks!

Comment: The errors above code strongly suggests that you have other memory management mistakes. You should audit your use of ivars, not just here. You should also post the actual crash.

Comment: OK, I'll give them a once over and get back to you. I'll post the Crash in a second.

Comment: Checked all ivars, even ran the Analyzer and fixed it's complaints, still no luck. Updated post with crash data and updated the SkyDrive source code to the most recent.

Comment: Overriding that method and tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: and having both return a constant fixed it. I'll mark you're answer as correct and open a new question on why I needed to do this. Thanks :)